# Google Suits SMTP does not use user input from_email when using send_mail() in Django framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, email, django-views, google-workspace

I created a contact form to receive messages from users. But when I check my inbox the email address attached to the user is the admin email address. I have checked my view logic and it seems to be correct. How do I solve this issue?

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@sample.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import forms

def contact(request):
    form = forms.ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            send_mail(
                form.cleaned_data['name'],
                form.cleaned_data['inquiry'],
                form.cleaned_data['from_email'],
                ['admin@sample.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('contact'))
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You may want to look at the content of "form" after "if form.is_valid():". Also, what does " is not what the user entered" mean? Is the field empty? Totally different Email? Only a few characters differ?  Be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the interest @AndreyBulezyuk The admin email address appears.

Comment: Can you try printing settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD and settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER? send_mail uses those values if you have them set.

Comment: @munsu I added the email setting

Comment: Not sure if this is related or why it should help, but try adding: ", reply_to=[form.cleaned_data['from_email']]" as parameter to "send_mail" after "['admin@sample.com"]

Comment: @AndreyBulezyuk just checked the documentation, reply_to will only list recipients.

Comment: I think this is an issue you get with using Google's SMTP. Google uses the account you authenticated with as the sender. See this similar case to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311635/from-email-not-showing-with-send-mail-smtp

Comment: @munsu read through the related question. Thanks for the help. The solution is a work around, need a complete solution. I am using G Suite services.

Comment: This will not change the sender but if you use the EmailMessage object, you can make use of reply_to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects. Once you hit reply on an email, it will automatically reply to the supplied email/s in reply_to.